# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміна portfolio pipeline

Tags: from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту ""PMBOK та PM ISO українською"". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Визначення терміна portfolio pipeline [там](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:tr:21506:ed-1:v1:en:term:3.48) таке:

> **portfolio pipeline** collection of opportunities considered for selection as portfolio components

Comment: Мені з цього витягу не зрозуміло, що таке *portfolio pipeline*. Чи не могли б ви навести приклад(и)?